# Regex Match only not keywords

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have a string like `<dlskjfldjf>Text creation List<string> checking edit<br/>`. Need help with regex to match only `<dlskjfldjf>` and not `List<string>`

Keyword could be any generic type like

```
IList<T>
List<T>
etc
```

I tried with `<([a-zA-Z]+)>` which would match `<dlskjfldjf>` and below which would match `List<string>` but not sure how to mix them both

```
((List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable)(<)([A-Za-z.,\[\]\s]*)(>))|(<T>)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you give a full example. Again am working with Google Appscript and as you know negative lookbehind doesn't work (as in other answers)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion `(?<! expression )`:

```
string pattern = @"(?<!(List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable))<([a-zA-Z]+)>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In a language that supports [Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) a pattern like this could work:

```
(?<!(List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable))<([a-zA-Z]+)>
```

In JavaScript you may need to use two patterns to achieve the same result, test once for the angle bracket pattern and then test again to ensure you don't have the type information preceding it.

Comment: negative look behind doesn't work for Google appscript. any other alternative

Comment: You'll probably like to remove the C# tag then. I don't have a good javascript solution for this in just one regex, you may need to use two?

Comment: Ahh!! absolutely big mistake ... removed

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is match what you don't want to keep, and capture in a group what you do want to keep:

```
\b(?:List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable)<[^<>]*>|(<[a-zA-Z]+>)
```

That will match:

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent any of the listed words in the alternation being part of a larger word
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable` Alternation which will match any of the listed words
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `<[^<>]*>` Match `<`, not `<>` 0+ times, then matc `>`
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture group (What you want to keep)

  - `<[a-zA-Z]+>` Match `<`, then 1+ times a lower or uppercase char, then `>`
- `)` Close capture group

For example:

```js
const regex = /\b(?:List|ilist|IList|IEnumerable|IQuerable)<[^<>]*>|(<[a-zA-Z]+>)/g;
const str = `<dlskjfldjf>Text creation List<string> checking edit<br/> or IList<string> or <aAbB>`;
let m;
let res = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1] !== undefined) res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```